# Why an arugment is missing in wp_get_attachment_image_attributes?

Tags: theme-development, images

I have a function:

```
  function azu_post_thumbnail_responsive_size($attr, $attachment, $size) {

    if ($size === 'az_medium') {

      $attr['sizes'] = '(max-width: 639px) 100vw, (max-width: 1023px) 50vw, 334px';

    } else if ($size === 'az_large') {

      $attr['sizes'] = '(max-width: 1023px) 100vw, 717px';

    }

    return $attr;

  }

  add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'azu_post_thumbnail_responsive_size', 10 , 3);
```

This is working fine on WP4.4+, but before, when responsive image were not introduced, I have the folowing error:

> Warning: Missing argument 3 for azu_post_thumbnail_responsive_size()

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter `$size` was introduced in WordPress 4.1. Before that there was only `$attr` and `$attachment`.

So for this to work before WP 4.1, you need to provide a default value for `$size`. Since default for size is `thumbnail`, you can use that in your filter hook's function definition.

So, modify your CODE as follows:

```
    function azu_post_thumbnail_responsive_size($attr, $attachment, $size = 'thumbnail') {
        if ($size === 'az_medium') {
            $attr['sizes'] = '(max-width: 639px) 100vw, (max-width: 1023px) 50vw, 334px';
        }
        else if ($size === 'az_large') {
            $attr['sizes'] = '(max-width: 1023px) 100vw, 717px';
        }
        return $attr;
    }

    add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'azu_post_thumbnail_responsive_size', 10 , 3);
```

Now it'll work for all versions of WordPress.

> Note: obviously, any CODE related to the `$size` parameter will not function similarly pre & post WP 4.1. However, at least you'll not get the error.